# powershell soaprequest with username and password

Tags: powershell, soap, powershell-2.0, webrequest

I need to make a Soap Request from Powershell, I am on Powershell 2.0, I can find lots of examples but I also need to include a username and password to get through the api.

I get a response of
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connectio
n was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

My Powershell code (I have redacted some sensitive stuff) is

```
function Execute-SOAPRequest 
( 
        [Xml]    $SOAPRequest, 
        [String] $URL 
) 
{ 
        write-host "Sending SOAP Request To Server: $URL" 
        $soapWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL) 
        $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","`"`"")

        $soapWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=`"utf-8`"" 
        $soapWebRequest.Accept      = "text/xml" 
        $soapWebRequest.Method      = "POST" 

        $username = "USERNAME"
        $password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
        $soapWebRequest.Credentials = $cred
        #$soapWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
        #$soapWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true           

        write-host $soapWebRequest

        write-host "Initiating Send."
        $requestStream = $soapWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
        write-host $requestStream 
        $SOAPRequest.Save($requestStream)  
        $requestStream.Close() 

        write-host "Send Complete, Waiting For Response." 
        $resp = $soapWebRequest.GetResponse() 
        $responseStream = $resp.GetResponseStream() 
        $soapReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]($responseStream) 
        $ReturnXml = [Xml] $soapReader.ReadToEnd() 
        $responseStream.Close() 

        write-host "Response Received."

        return $ReturnXml 
}

$url = 'https://zkncsavia049.via.novonet:7180/ws/activeservices/pmspapi_nomination'
$soap = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:pms="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/pmsapi_nomination" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wssu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security><wsse:UsernameToken wssu:Id="UsernameToken-4B81F4838BB6D8A60715299310629901"><wsse:Username>igyadmin</wsse:Username>
             <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">V3rm0nt</wsse:Password>
             <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">x9DSipKzGHLbvyCOXKIY6A==</wsse:Nonce>
             <wssu:Created>2018-06-25T12:51:02.986Z</wssu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>     
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pms:pmsapi_nomination.getlist.ApiRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/pmsapi_nomination">
         <ApiRequest>
            <LogonInfo>
               <BusinessGroup>GMP</BusinessGroup>
               <AdminGroup>ADMN</AdminGroup>
            </LogonInfo>
            <BUSINESS_GROUP>
               <value>GMP</value>
            </BUSINESS_GROUP>
            <CONTEXT>
               <value>F</value>
            </CONTEXT>
            <REFNO>
               <value>0039760</value>
            </REFNO>
         </ApiRequest>
      </pms:pmsapi_nomination.getlist.ApiRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'@

$ret = Execute-SOAPRequest $soap $url
```

I can get the call to work through SOAPUI the raw XML is

```
POST http://zkncsavia049.via.novonet:7180/ws/activeservices/pmsapi_nomination/HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 1541
Host: zkncsavia049.via.novonet:7180
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:pms="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/pmsapi_nomination" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wssu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security><wsse:UsernameToken wssu:Id="UsernameToken-78C15367B2B1287BB3153000735070610"><wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">q5B6XRmHsecmHouCqH03qA==</wsse:Nonce><wssu:Created>2018-06-26T10:02:30.696Z</wssu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>     
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pms:pmsapi_nomination.getlist.ApiRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.aquilauk.co.uk/pmsapi_nomination">
         <ApiRequest>
            <LogonInfo>
               <BusinessGroup>GMP</BusinessGroup>
               <AdminGroup>ADMN</AdminGroup>
            </LogonInfo>
            <BUSINESS_GROUP>
               <value>GMP</value>
            </BUSINESS_GROUP>
            <CONTEXT>
               <value>F</value>
            </CONTEXT>
            <REFNO>
               <value>0039761</value>
            </REFNO>
         </ApiRequest>
      </pms:pmsapi_nomination.getlist.ApiRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is an SSL certificate on the system but not for port 7180.

I'm also very much a powershell novice, I only write it a couple of times a year.

So the fail is on

```
$resp = $soapWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

but I guess that the setting up of $soapWebRequest may be the problem